# Vba interagindo com o IE

Tags: vba

Preciso clicar num elemento de um site:

[image: Código Html]

O problema é que são vários destes e fiz este codigo:

```
For Each obj In ie.Document.all
    obj.Click
Next
```

Mas este codigo clica em todos os objetos da pagina nao consigo apenas nos ojbetos específicos?

Nao existe um ie.Document.all que faça a função obj.click em apenas na parte que estao os botões que quero clicar ou um codigo que clica em apenas os objetos que tenham em sua class: "clicavel" para nao clicar em todos da pagina.

Comment: Favor não inserir código como imagem e qual é o site?

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia,

Tente assim:

```
For Each obj In ie.Document.all
    if obj.id = "img_684517_43_2506" then
        obj.Click
    end if
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Se os objetos que você pretende clicar são os da classe `clicavel`, é só iterar usando o método `getElementsByClassName`:

```
For Each obj In IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("clicavel")
    obj.Click
Next
```

Se forem apenas alguns objetos da classe clicável, coloca um `if`dentro do `for`, para clicar apenas nos que você quer.

Comment: Cara, deu um erro em tempo de execução '438'; O objeto não aceita esta propriedade ou método

Comment: Você pode dizer em que linha dá o erro?
Se for na linha `obj.Click`, considerando que o script itera todos os objetos da classe "clicavel", pode dar uma olhada em qual é o objeto que está ativo quando dá o erro? Provavelmente, esse objeto não pode receber o método `.Click`, ou algo assim.

Comment: nesta linha     For Each obj In ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("clicavel")

Comment: Talvez você esteja tentando atribuir um objeto de um tipo a uma variável de outro. Todos os objetos da classe `clicavel` na página do SBE são a mesma categoria? Por exemplo, se sua variável `obj` estiver declarada como `HTMLimg` e na página houver um objeto `INPUT` com a classe `clicavel`, quando chegar a vez dele na iteração, o código vai tentar atribuir o objeto, que é `INPUT`, a uma variável `HTMLImg`, e vai dar esse erro. A variável `obj`, como está declarada? Por via das dúvidas, tente declarar `obj` como `variant`, veja se resolve. Se não resolver, tente iterar com um contador numérico.